# tkinter : Fill scrollable canvas with frame content

Tags: python, tkinter

I've searched a lot but found no way to properly fill a scrollable canvas with this content frame. There is always extra space.

In the code below found on SO and adapted to a simple example, I want my `DummyFrame` components to take all the extra space left of the canvas.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class DummyFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root, borderwidth=10, background="#ff0000")
        tk.Label(self, text="DummyLabel").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="wnes")
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(root, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, borderwidth=10, background="#000000")
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)

        self.vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="wnes")
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="wnes")
        self.canvas.create_window((0,0), window=self.frame, anchor="nw", 
                                  tags="self.frame")

        self.frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.OnFrameConfigure)

        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.populate()

    def populate(self):
        for i_row in range(50):
            #Component I want to take extra space when resizing window
            DummyFrame(self.frame).grid(row = i_row+1, column = 0, sticky="we")

    def OnFrameConfigure(self, event):
        '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fenetre = tk.Tk()
    fenetre.geometry('{}x{}'.format(800, 600))
    Example(fenetre)
    fenetre.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    fenetre.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    fenetre.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please add current output and expected output to make what you want more clear

Answer (score 0):

This example is very strangely destined. So you have DummyFrames in a Frame in a canvas window which is in a canvas in a Frame. Its difficult to see what is happening here, and which widget dimension control most the resulting dimension the user sees. Nevertheless, if you want to make the DummyFrame as width as your root window (i.e. 800 px) just change the canvas window width:

```
self.canvas.create_window((0,0), window=self.frame, anchor="nw", 
                          width=800,
                          tags="self.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks, to sum up, I want a list of frames in a scroll frame and the whole thing is resizable. Your answer does not allow resizing the window. But maybe having a list of frames in a scroll frame is not a good thing...

Answer (score -1):

Finaly I found something fitted my needs using itemconfigure of the canvas:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class DummyFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root, borderwidth=10, background="#ff0000")
        tk.Label(self, text="DummyLabel").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="wnes")
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        pass

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(root, borderwidth=0, background="#0000ff")
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.OnCanvasConfigure)
        self.vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="wnes")
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="wnes")

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, borderwidth=10, background="#000000")
        self.frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.window = self.canvas.create_window((0,0), window=self.frame, anchor="nw",
                          tags="self.frame")

        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.populate()

    def populate(self):
        for i_row in range(50):
            #Component I want to take extra space when resizing window
            DummyFrame(self.frame).grid(row = i_row+1, column = 0, sticky="we")

    def OnCanvasConfigure(self, event):
        self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.window, width=event.width)
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fenetre = tk.Tk()
    fenetre.geometry('{}x{}'.format(800, 600))
    Example(fenetre)
    fenetre.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    fenetre.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    fenetre.mainloop()
```